# "Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Android\sdk]!" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I could use the emulator properly two days ago and now it does not work.

I understand there are many people facing this problem. I have read many of them and tried the solutions stated there (set/change the environment variable of ANDROID_SDK_ROOT & ANDROID_HOME, re-install Android Studio, check avd file, etc.), but did not solve the problem.

My sdk file is in C:\Android\sdk and that is the place where Android SDK Manager in Android Studio found Android SDK as is existing. I have set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value to C:\Android\sdk. I do not know what else to do. Is there anyone who knows how to resolve this?

I am using Android Studio 3.5.3 on Windows 10.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem recently and got it solved after doing some googling and trying..
It's because the emulator can't read path that containing non-ascii strings properly and in default AVD-specific files are located at `C:/Users/%USERNAME%/.android/avd/`, but somehow the error log doesn't give right hint and mislead us to focus on `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, so you only need to add `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` variable with a ascii path like `ANDROID_AVD_HOME=D:\Android_avd` and restart your IDE. After that your emulator will run properly.

More info https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables

Update: You may need to create a subdirectory `.android` like `C:\test\.android` and add a `ANDROID_SDK_HOME=C:\test` variable, then add a empty `.emulator_console_auth_token` file which locates at the corresponding floder according to the error log, for me it's `C:\Users\鍑濈传绉嬭悓\.emulator_console_auth_token`.
After that you should run it without any error, I've already tested it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. By adding ANDROID_AVD_HOME with its value to be C:\Android\sdk, the emulator itself successfully ran, however, without an app that I am making. There are two error messages arose: `Emulator: ERROR: Unable to access 'C:\Users\Username\.emulator_console_auth_token': emulator console will not work` and `Emulator: emulator: WARNING: IniFile.cpp:235: Failed to open .ini file C:\Users\Username\.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for writing.` My username is not in English, so it is corrupted.

Comment: An error message `Emulator: ERROR: Unable to access 'C:\Users\Username\.emulator_console_auth_token': emulator console will not work` is still remaining...

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24988

https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/6of9kp/error_when_starting_emulator_panic_broken_avd/dkgzing/

https://inneka.com/programming/android/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android_sdk_root-value/

You might not need to setup path. Try to run without path.

Comment: Now it says "Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT"

Comment: Mozuha hmm it looks strange